# Chrome Installation errors with: "Egads! Installation Failed"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install the Chrome on my Windows 7 machine using PowerShell.

The download is successful but installation is failing, but it is failing with the error:

> Egads! Installation Failed

I found some manually process for solving the issue like delete Chrome folder in Program Files.

```
$saveFilePath="$PSScriptRoot\chrome_installer.exe"
$url="https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe"
$downloader = (new-object System.Net.WebClient)
$downloader.DownloadFile("$url", "$saveFilePath")
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "$saveFilePath" -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop;
```

Comment: First link in Google search about "Egads! Installation Failed" https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/google-chrome-egads-installation-failed-error-code/c4849665-544b-4e29-87bd-93e4512fe063

Comment: @ montonero   It does not say thing we can do with program. as i mentioned i found some manual solution this is one of that.we have to delete some folders and some programs that we can not do it by script without knowing what is that some?

Comment: So your issue is about how to remove folders in Powershell? Have you tried?

Comment: @montonero  No as the link says **If you have additional subfolders in your "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google" or C:\Program Files\Google" folder, you may want to uninstall the other programs before doing this and reinstall them afterwards.** . Here what is other programs means? even i deleted the Google folder in program files manually still i am getting the error.

Comment: use "remove-item" to remove a folder and "test-path" to check if a folder exists. don't want to be rude but have you even tried asking google?

Comment: @ D.J its not about removal of folder or file. its about what to delete whether it is folder and programs. even though i deleted the folder manually still i am facing the issue. i searched the google most answers lead me to the manual operations. i am running a script to install so i can not do manual work.  so any code help please.

Comment: It's not clear which problem with *code* you have. As far as I see your issue is not with code but with Chrome installer and this is not quite relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: @montonero  this line of code $process = Start-Process -FilePath "$saveFilePath" -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop;  gives the errror what i mentioned. so i am looking for any other solution which can resolve the error. if i run the installer manually by double click it is installing properly . then there is a problem in the installation with powershell. i am looking for help in avoid error while running powershell script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you have used is incorrect. You'll need to use "/SILENT /INSTALL" instead of "/QUIET".

See here for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/337210/how-can-i-silently-install-google-chrome